# Is there a book that is specifically written for OpenCV 2.2?

Tags: .net, opencv

I have been finding a book for OpenCV, but [Learning OpenCV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) is all what I can find. Unfortunately, the book is written for OpenCV 1.1 and is quite out of date. So I searched in Stackoverflow and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721005/is-learning-opencv-the-book-relevant-after-opencv-2) thread. After reading the thread, I understand I can still learn OpenCV from the book, but I am afraid the code differences between OpenCV 1.1 and 2.2 will make learning OpenCV frustrating, especially for a complete novice like me.
Currently I am finding for a book or tutorial website that is specifically written for OpenCV 2.2, so I can follow the code in the book and get started more easily.

By the way, I would like to know that which language integrates best with OpenCV? I am wondering is using Emgu CV (OpenCV for .net) with C#.net a good choice?
Thanks!

Comment: As for the "best" integration, for opencv 2.x C++ is the choice closest to opencv. The C interface is not as nice, and everything else means using a wrapper, which means there can be additional bugs or missing exposed functionality.

Comment: Correction: the Learning OpenCV book is written for OpenCV 2.1, not 1.1. Also, if you're worried about the differences between what's in the book and the current version of , why not just use 2.1? Later, when you've found your way around OpenCV, you can learn the differences to 2.2.

Comment: @etarion : Thanks for the info. I decided to use C# at first because I am more familiar with Java than C++, so switching from Java to C# would be easier. But after reading your comments, I think I should try to code in C++.

Comment: @carnieri : Thanks for the correction. The reason why I would like to use EmguCV 2.2 is that it supports Visual Studio 2010, the IDE I am using now.

Comment: You can have a look at a site I maintain: http://aishack.in/ :) I've put up some articles that might be useful to you.

Comment: @Utkarsh Sinha : Wow! Really great stuffs. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

[OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513244) was published in June 2011. It covers the newer C++ APIs, so it may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

No, Learning OpenCV is the closest you'll get to a structured exposition on OpenCV. But you can still use the techniques and functions (by slightly changing the function names) described in the book in OpenCV 2.2 with the [documentation of OpenCV 2.1](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a novice you should first get a basic understanding of Computer Vision topics and then start to learn a cv library such as openCV.

To have an overall idea on Computer Vision "Learning Opencv" is a good starting point, then you can directly study the new opencv examples and unit test.

Emgu CV is a good choice if you are a novice and familiar with Java